# object id nil first time every time swift parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification

I am implementing parse in a swift project. I am using the  objectid of a device as the unique identifier for sending out notifications. I grab this value and store it in my db for every user.

I have the following methods implemented:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        println("get in here every time?")
        let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)

        installation.saveInBackground()

        if installation.objectId != nil {
            installation.setObject(installation.objectId!, forKey: "userName")
            updateNotificationIDWebServiceCall(installation.objectId!)
        }
        else{
            println("object id was nil. Device token was: \(deviceToken).")
            //JLToast.makeText("object id was nil. Device token was: \(deviceToken).").show()
        }
        installation.saveInBackground()
    }
```

I am successfully getting into this method on app launch but my object id is always nil, the first time the app is installed.

If the user kills off the app and re-launches, the objectid is no longer nil and I can update my backend with the correct identifier for each user but, my issue is with people who put the app in the background and don't even know how to kill off an app.

How can I get around this? Can I put some code in the didBecomeActive? I couldn't seem to find a callback for the saveInBackground method.

Also here is my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        Prefs.notificationToShow = true

        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        //UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

        if (PFInstallation.currentInstallation().badge != 0) {
            PFInstallation.currentInstallation().badge = 0
            PFInstallation.currentInstallation().saveInBackground()
        }
        Parse.setApplicationId("xxx",
            clientKey: "yyy")

        // Register for Push Notitications
        if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
            // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
            // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
            // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.

            let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
            let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
            var pushPayload = false
            if let options = launchOptions {
                pushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil
            }
            if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || pushPayload) {
                PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
            }
        }
        if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
            let userNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        } else {
            let types = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }

        NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(1);
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = true
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        Fabric.with([Twitter(), Crashlytics()])

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the objectId of the installation object is nil, however I have an alternative method that may be of interest for you.

Rather than saving the objectId of the installation to a user for a unique identifier, consider saving a pointer to the current user within each installation. Every device will get it's own installation object and it is possible that one user could have many devices.

You will need to have a way to send push notifications to all of their devices, but under your current design each user is limited to one device.

By adding the user pointer to each installation object, you will be able to query for and create sets of users to send out notifications.

It may also be worthwhile to add some debugging code to make sure that Parse is saving the installations without errors. Change your `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` to have the following:

```
installation.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (success) {
        println("success - didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken")
    } else {
        //  Log details of the failure
        println("failure - didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken")
        println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I am updating the notificationID on app launch, so if a user logs in on a second device, their id will be updated and the notification sent to the new device. We are not supporting sending out notifications to more than one device per user. Any suggestions on why the objectID is nil 1st time or a work around on how to grab it in the didbecomeactive or elsewhere ? My client wants this as the demographic of the app are users who are likely not to actively kill off apps and thus, the notificationID on my backend remains nil. Is there a callback for when it is retrieved?

Comment: Just updated the answer to have the completion block for saving/debugging errors. I think the issue is that you are using two different saves within `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`. I'm pretty sure that the issue is that the objectId will be nil until it has been saved to Parse. Since the saving is done asynchronously in the background, you are currently trying to access the objectId of the installation when it hasn't completed being saved

Comment: great, this was my thinking. Will try out the different method above and report back